# Offline use of validator_cli.jar: prevent Internet access attempts

Tags: hapi

Older editions of validator_cli.jar - up to 5.4.12 or thereabouts - were perfectly usable in an offline context (i.e. without an Internet connection), as long as the `-tx n/a` switch was supplied and the FHIR package cache in the user directory had all the required packages.

No such luck with newer editions, though. They insist on contacting package servers to check for updates for the `hl7.terminology` package and then they throw a fit when they cannot contact a 'build server' (whatever that may be):

```
FHIR Validation tool Version 5.6.27 (Git# 90008b77449d). Built 2022-01-21T21:43:46.20Z (58 hours old)
  Java:   16.0.1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1 on amd64 (64bit). 4068MB available
  Paths:  Current = k:\download\FHIR\validator_cli, Package Cache = C:\Users\Entwicklung\.fhir\packages
  Params: -tx n/a -version 4.0.1 d:\dev\FHIR\Beispieldaten\Basic\Basic_minimal.xml
Loading
  Load FHIR v4.0 from hl7.fhir.r4.core#4.0.1 - 4575 resources (00:04.0161)
2022-01-24 09:09:59.355 [main] INFO  o.h.f.u.n.FilesystemPackageCacheManager [FilesystemPackageCacheManager.java:232] Failed to determine latest version of package hl7.terminology from server: http://packages.fhir.org
2022-01-24 09:09:59.449 [main] INFO  o.h.f.u.n.FilesystemPackageCacheManager [FilesystemPackageCacheManager.java:232] Failed to determine latest version of package hl7.terminology from server: https://packages2.fhir.org/packages
Error connecting to build server - running without build (build.fhir.org)
java.net.UnknownHostException: build.fhir.org
```

Also, the futile attempts at connecting via the Internet can cause eternal delays, depending on the network stack and its current state.

Is there some secret switch that would make newer editions as well-behaved as the older ones? Are there other workarounds that could be used to mitigate?

If all else fails: what would be the most direct route to fixing the situation? I've half a mind to redirect packages.fhir.org and build.fhir.org to a fake package/build server via the hosts file, but I could not locate information regarding the build server API.

*P.S.: I beg to consider that uncontrolled Internet access attemps are strict no-no in a health care context (at least in Europe). And the validator could easily be used to infiltrate hundreds of megabytes of data, by dint of publishing an apposite package on Simplifier and then circulating a resource that references that package. Simplifier does not vet the packages it publishes (it obviously doesn't even *validate* the contained profiles, at least not with a decently capable validator like HAPI; earlier versions of the profile packages published by the German organisation tasked with coordinating electronic prescriptions were so broken that they caused HAPI to **crash** and no-one noticed for a handful of months).*

Answer (score 0):

no there isn't a switch like that and the reason is because the validator isn't written to be used in a production server.

Comment: Are you saying that it was written to only ever see artificial test samples, never to be run against any piece of real data? Real FHIR data almost invariably means health care data, which means that data and unrestricted Internet access are not allowed to coexist in the same place. By law. At least not in Europe.

Comment: Besides, lookup attempts for missing profiles by trying to reference the profile URLs are not only of questionable utility, they also undermine the validation result because such lookups have no defined semantics. Which version of the profile in question should such a lookup return?

Comment: Package depot access (`packages.simplifier.net` & Co.) can be cleanly and effectively proxied (redirected to a well curated package depot on disk) and a local terminology server can be specified via a command line option. However, *the other* Internet access attempts cannot be effectively proxied/stubbed, for two reasons. The first is lack of defined semantics, and the second is that faking out HTTPS accesses raises the same difficulties as HTTPS inspection (on-the-fly faking of SSL certificates etc. pp.).

Comment: Last but not least, I do run all my production data through the validator CLI (as well as against several other oracles), because the whole electronic prescriptions thing in Germany is still very much *in statu nascendi* and I want to reduce residual risks for our clients to the lowest amount possible.

Comment: P.S.: I left out the question of accessing referenced resources, which is a different kettle of fish altogether and a complete non-issue in certain usage scenarios (e.g. data exchange *between* organisations/sites, as opposed to site-local traffic).